# Complex date column case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, denodo

I need a small help, I am having a date field that has a  format like this in a column COL1

```
COL1

yyyy-MM-dd
dd-MMM-yy
ddMMMYYYY
```

The query I have is

```
    case WHEN ("COL1" like '%-%') THEN to_localdate('yyyy-MM-dd', "COL1")  
    WHEN ("COL1" like '%-%') THEN to_localdate('dd/MMM/yy', "COL1") 
    ELSE to_localdate('ddMMMyyyy', "COL1") END AS COL1
```

I am not sure how to process the dd-MMM-yy field here in my case statement.

Thanks,

Note: I am using Oracle and running queries on denodo. But this is just SQL case statement. So it should work everywhere.

Comment: But of course the entire difficulty comes from the serioiusly flawed data design of using a string data type for dates instead of oracle's DATE.  With a proper data type for dates, this current problem (and many future problems)  ceases to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the column contains valid formatted dates, use the `_` wildcard which represents a single character:

```
CASE 
  WHEN ("COL1" LIKE '____-__-__') THEN to_localdate('yyyy-MM-dd', "COL1")  
  WHEN ("COL1" like '__/___/__') THEN to_localdate('dd/MMM/yy', "COL1") 
  ELSE to_localdate('ddMMMyyyy', "COL1") 
END AS COL1
```

Comment: @Olivier Jacot-Descombes thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_like()`.  I think this is the logic:

```
(case when regexp_like('^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$' 
     then to_localdate('yyyy-MM-dd', COL1) 
     when regexp_like('^[0-9]{2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{2}$' 
     then to_localdate('dd-MMM-rr', COL1) 
     when regexp_like('^[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}$' 
     then to_localdate('ddMMMrr', COL1) 
end)
```